# Switching 2 light fixtures

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding, light

I'm trying to swap the light fixtures in two rooms of my house. Both of the fixtures have both green and bare copper wires and while in one fixture only the green was connected and in the other fixture they both were - my question is, as these are both grounds, what would be the reasoning behind connecting both the green and bare copper wires? Are they not both grounds or is it just a redundancy?

Comment: If the fixtures have two pieces, then imagine one of the grounds make sure the second piece is grounded also, as in a hanging light fixture.

Comment: @crip659 might as well write that up, it's the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two ground wires usually used when a device has two or more pieces, and ground can be broken or not guaranteed  between them.

Like a light fixture with a chain holding a lower part or a part separated by plastic.